# Strange outgoing messages in syslog, mail.log

Tags: ubuntu, logs, sendmail

I am not using the email config in my ubuntu server, can anyone tell me what is going on?
[image]

Comment: Your server is sending spam and should therefore be regarded as compromised: [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/39231/138009)

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086)

Answer (score 0):

Your server is trying to send spam; this means that it has been hacked.

You should put it offline ASAP and reinstall it. (That's the only way to be sure. Restoring a previous backup image won't work if you don't know *when* the breach happened.)

Once you have a fresh server again, keep it hardened:

- Install promptly all updates and security patches as they come out
- Disable all unnecessary services to minimize the attack vector
- Use strong passwords and strong method of access (e.g disable root login and use pubkey authentication for the other SSH user login).